# SQL XML Full-Text Search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, xquery, xquery-sql

I am implementing search-functionality into a web-application and have enabled Full-Text Search on a number of columns in my table.

One of those columns is of the datatype 'xml' and i'm currently using XQuery to make sure only certain nodes are searched.

Here is an example of the XQuery part of an SQL-Query (The SQL-Query is a generated/dynamic query)

```
XMLContent.exist('/Template/Fields/Field/Text/text()[contains(.,"search-phrase1") or contains(.,"search-phrase2") or contains(.,"etc.")]') = 1
```

The dynamic query can put any number of search-phrases in to the query.

When i was learning how to write this query i got the impression that this is utilizing Full-Text Search but i tried removing the Full-Text Index on the XMLContent-column and the query still runs.

My question is if it's faster to use the CONTAINS-function in sql to search the entire XMLContent-column or is it faster when i narrow it down to just specific nodes in the xml?

Does the different methods have their own benefits except that the CONTAINS checks all nodes rather than the specified one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are 2 different contains functions. They don't talk to each other.

1. Full-text contains: Contains(XmlContent,'Ford')
2. Xml contains: XmlContent.exist('/Cars/text()[contains(.,"Ford")]') =1

I have a table with 10000 rows, run below 3 queries in SSMS with *Include Actual Execution Plan*

```
Select * from TableA where Contains(XmlContent,'Ford') and XmlContent.exist('/Cars/text()[contains(.,"Ford")]') =1
Select * from TableA where Contains(XmlContent,'Ford')
Select * from TableA where XmlContent.exist('/Cars/text()[contains(.,"Ford")]') =1
```

The execution plan shows

```
Query1: Query Cost (relative to the batch): 3%
Query2: Query Cost (relative to the batch): 2%
Query3: Query Cost (relative to the batch): 95%
```

The full-text contains() excludes irrelevant rows very quick with little effort. Highly Recommended. you can use both versions' of contains().

Not sure about the specific-node-narrow-down, you may write similar queries in SSMS, it will tell you if it works.

Here is a [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522491.aspx) page